# Android Intent getExtras

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-intent

I am passing values between two activities and fetching the values like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)

    {
        initialUrl = extras.getString("initialUrl");
        isFollow = extras.getString("isFollow");
    }


    if (isFollow == "true") {
        editUrl.setText(initialUrl);
        setUpWebView(initialUrl);
    } else if (isFollow == "false") {
        editUrl.setText("http://www.google.com");
        setUpWebView("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

the problem is I can see the values being retrieved in the debug window by adding watch to the variables but when the compiler enters the statement if(isFollow=="true"), the condition fails. The else case is also not dealt with. What else do i need to do to ensure that my if condition is satisfied properly?

Comment: Firstly send boolean in bundle and also if you are sending text then compare using equals not using ==

Comment: == tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
isFollow.equals("true")
```

in your statements.

Answer (score 1):

If String type of data is put in bundle then Try with the following code

```
String isFollow = null;    
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)

    {
        initialUrl = extras.getString("initialUrl");
        isFollow = extras.getString("isFollow");
    }
if (isFollow.equals("true")) {
        editUrl.setText(initialUrl);
        setUpWebView(initialUrl);
    } else if (isFollow.equals("false")) {
        editUrl.setText("http://www.google.com");
        setUpWebView("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

If Boolean type of data is put in bundle then Try with the following code

```
 boolean isFollow = null;    
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null)

        {
            initialUrl = extras.getString("initialUrl");
            isFollow = extras.getBoolean("isFollow");
        }
    if (isFollow) {
            editUrl.setText(initialUrl);
            setUpWebView(initialUrl);
        } else {
            editUrl.setText("http://www.google.com");
            setUpWebView("http://www.google.com");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test either 
`isFollow.equals("true")` or if it is a boolean and not a string, either
`isFollow == true` or just plain `isFollow`

(note the no quotes on the second one)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really late answer but it would be better to do this if you are passing a Boolean into the intent from the sender:

```
Boolean isFollow = extras.getBoolean("isFollow");

if(isFollow) { 
  //Do stuff
}
```